# FeathersJS Twitch OAuth 401 Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, feathersjs

I'm new to FeathersJS. I tried to set up OAuth login with Twitch. I created a twitch oauth application and did the same as [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/authentication.html#github-login-oauth) with github login. I want to save the user in my MongoDB database, but I'm getting redirected to **http://localhost:3030/#error=401%20Unauthorized** after logging in on twitch. I've generated a fresh application with the feathers cli. What am I doing wrong?

**config/default.json**

```
...
"oauth": {
  "redirect": "/",
  "twitch": {
    "key": ""*****************",",
    "secret": ""***************************************"",
    "scope": ["user:read:email"]
  },
  "github": {
    "key": "*****************",
    "secret": "***************************************"
  }
}...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the built-in strategy is attempting to fetch the user profile, yet it is not including your Client ID in the headers (see [Twitch API - Getting Started](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api).

To solve this you need to create your own strategy that implements `getProfile`. I used the Facebook demo from the feathersjs cookbook as a reference [which can be found here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/cookbook/authentication/facebook.html#getting-profile-data).

Here is my implementation:

*./strategies/TwitchStrategy.ts*

```js
import { Params } from '@feathersjs/feathers'
import { AuthenticationRequest } from '@feathersjs/authentication'
import { OAuthStrategy, OAuthProfile } from '@feathersjs/authentication-oauth'
import axios from 'axios'
import { Application } from '../declarations'

export class TwitchStrategy extends OAuthStrategy {
    // we need a reference to the app instance
    app: Application = {} as Application

    // when the strategy is initialized this method is called with an app instance
    setApplication(appInstance: Application): void {
        this.app = appInstance
    }

    // this method is used to get the user profile after they authorize with the provider
    async getProfile(authResult: AuthenticationRequest, _params: Params) {
        const accessToken = authResult.access_token

        const { data } = await axios.get('https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users', {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`, //our users access token to look them up
                'Client-ID': this.app.get('authentication').oauth.twitch.key //we need to send the Client-ID
            },
            params: {
                fields: 'id,name,email'
            }
        })

        console.log(data)

        return data
    }

    async getEntityData(profile: OAuthProfile, existing: any, params: Params) {
        // `profile` is the data returned by getProfile
        const baseData = await super.getEntityData(profile, existing, params)

        return {
            ...baseData,
            email: profile.email
        }
    }
}
```

*./authentication.ts*

```js
import { ServiceAddons } from '@feathersjs/feathers'
import { AuthenticationService, JWTStrategy } from '@feathersjs/authentication'
import { LocalStrategy } from '@feathersjs/authentication-local'
// import our strategy
import { TwitchStrategy } from './strategies/TwitchStrategy'
import { expressOauth } from '@feathersjs/authentication-oauth'
import { Application } from './declarations'

declare module './declarations' {
    interface ServiceTypes {
        authentication: AuthenticationService & ServiceAddons<any>
    }
}

export default function (app: Application): void {
    const authentication = new AuthenticationService(app)
    authentication.register('jwt', new JWTStrategy())
    // register our custom strategy
    authentication.register('twitch', new TwitchStrategy())
    authentication.register('local', new LocalStrategy())

    app.use('/authentication', authentication)
    app.configure(expressOauth())
}
```